# How to match a pattern in the middle of another text?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to use java regex to fetch a number from a given URL.

The problem is the pattern should appear in the middle of the URL.

How can I fix my regex?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[.w]*/pins/[.d]+/edit");
Matcher m = p.matcher("https://mysite.com/providers/271/pins/4997/edit");
while (m.find()) {
    String id = m.group();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to match `4997` and have no restrictions in your `Pattern` to validate the `URL` (which shouldn't be done with regex anyway), then you can use a simple solution based on "lookarounds":

```
String url = "https://mysite.com/providers/271/pins/4997/edit";
//                           | preceded by "pins/"
//                           |         | 1 or more digits 
//                           |         |   | followed by "/edit"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=pins/)\\d+(?=/edit)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) {
    //                   | whole group will only capture "\\d+"
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
4997
```

Comment: missing capturing group arround \\d

Comment: @JEY not really no. See also comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the number between pins and edit then try the below regex,

```
(?<=pins\/)(\d+)(?=\/edit)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yI3iS2/8)

Java regex would be,

```
"(?<=pins\\/)(\\d+)(?=\\/edit)"
```

Your Java code would be,

```
String s = "https://mysite.com/providers/271/pins/4997/edit";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=pins/)(\\d+)(?=/edit)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
          System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Output:

```
4997
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/zhSeGQ)

Comment: `/` is not special in Java regex, you don't need to escape it, which means you probably shouldn't to avoid confusing people (especially those new to Java regex).

Answer (score 1):

Try `pins/(\d+)/edit$` with minor changes in your regex pattern.

Here `$` represents end of the line and parenthesis `()` are used to group the digits matched inside `pins` and `edit`.

Sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("pins/(\\d+)/edit$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("https://mysite.com/providers/271/pins/4997/edit");
if (m.find()) {
    String id = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(id); // 4997
}
```

---

You can use `String#split()` method as well.

Sample code:

```
String str = "https://mysite.com/providers/271/pins/4997/edit";
String[] arr = str.split("/");
System.out.println(arr[arr.length - 2]); // 4997
```